# CodeIgniter HMVC routes

Tags: codeigniter, routes, hmvc

Currently working on a CodeIgniter application using HMVC

The HMVC app has his own routing.php containing

```
$route['finance/bill/add'] = 'finance/show_addBill';

$route['finance/transaction/add'] = 'finance/show_addTransaction';

$route['finance/(:any)'] = 'finance/$1';

$route['finance'] = 'finance';
```

the application has an Finance controller.
When going to

```
http://localhost/finance** it goes to **public function index(){}

http://localhost/finance/transaction/add DOES NOT go to **public function show_addTransaction() {}

http://localhost/finance/addTransaction DOES goes to **public function show_addTransaction() {}
```

I can not figure out why above routes aren't working :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be defining routes in an HMVC application (as a very strong rule of thumb - there are exceptions but it is rare).

You should have a folder structure like:

```
Modules
- Finance
- - Controllers
- - - finance //should have index, add and an other generic functions.
- - - transaction // transactions specific functions
- - - bill // bill specific functions.
```

The routing is automatic - along these lines:

`url/finance` -> look for `Modules/Finance/Controllers/Finance/Index()`

`url/finance/bill` -> it will look for `Modules/Finance/Controllers/Finance(.php)/Bill()` FIRST then `Modules/Finance/Controllers/Bill(.php)/index()`

So for your scenario you should have:

```
$route['finance/bill/add']
```

A `bill.php` controller - with `class bill` - with a method `add`

```
$route['finance/transaction/add']
```

A `transaction.php` controller - with `class transaction` - with a method `add`

```
$route['finance/(:any)']
```

Doesn't exist - as I said the URL routing is automatic so provided you have the relevant controllers and methods things will be found

```
$route['finance']
```

Simple `finance.php` controller with `index` method.